# WCF / DB Connection timeout on WAN

Tags: database, wcf, timeout, excel-addins, wan

We have created an Excel addin which consumes a WCF service and which is working fine at London office (where the service and DB sits), but we are getting a timeout error when accessing the same service via Excel Addin from Singapore or HongKong.

This was working fine for nearly an year and one day it suddenly went down. More details below

When opening up the Excel Addin,

- It successfully loads the parameter lists from the service (here I can say both service and Addin works fine from Singapore), the amount of data extracts from DB, then from the service is relatively small.
- When I select the parameters and try to extract a large amount of data from Service, the connection gets timeout. Which is working fine at London office and it takes only around 20 secconds to download the whole data.

The initial investigation proves that the service gets timeout when accessing on WAN. We have checked both antivirus and firewall but couldn't find any issues.

Any inputs on this will be highly appreciated.